# Terminal not executing hive queries

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am able to execute hive queries in hive shell after starting hive

```
hive> show databases;
OK
default
spot

Time taken: 0.051 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

But I am unable to execute the same query directly from terminal (as i want to include it in my bash script later). I am getting following error

```
hive -e "show databases"


FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

Comment: Have you tried using beeline instead?

Comment: Nope. I need it with other Hadoop services for a project. All the hive queries are already made, just want to run it on using bash script.

Comment: Sure, but Hive cli is deprecated and replaceable by beeline